# Таймер на переадресацию

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на это поставить таймер

```
<script>location.href='';</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout) сделает `location.href=''` через 1 секунду:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    location.href='';
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout_id = window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href='';}, delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

А причем тут PHP?

если на PHP то можно так сделать

```
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" Content=\"100; URL=index.php\">";
```